# How to upgrade an existing Azure Function v2.0 beta to v2.0 GA?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Azure Function v2 is now GA.

I have existing Azure Functions that currently running with the v2 beta, as shown below:

[image: Azure Function App settings]

**Question**

How can I make them running with the brand new 2.0 runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Application settings of Azure portal, set `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to ~2.

Comment: To be clear, you were already running the v2 GA bits before changing it to ~2. But setting it to ~2 is the right thing to do.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Well I have been using the preview version of Azure Function v2 for a long time. Once I got the news of v2 being GA'd, I went to my Function App page and saw what you can see in the screenshot: it was saying that the runtime version was still beta. Changing the parameter as recommended by Jerry Liu fixed" it.

Comment: The fact that it said 'beta' simply reflected the value of your app setting. But by that point, you were actually already using the GA build, since beta means *The latest build, whether it's release or pre-release*. As you can see, the actual build number stayed the same after you changed to ~2 (`2.0.12115`).